# React dropdown close

Tags: reactjs

```
code
<select open={false} autoFocus={true} onClick={this.handleClick} size={5}>
  <option value="grapefruit">Grapefruit</option>
  <option value="lime">Lime</option>
  <option value="coconut">Coconut</option>
  <option value="mango">Mango</option>
</select>
```

I have done drop down implementation.
i could not close it.
i do not want close it by "display:none"
any help will be appricated

Comment: by using ref, assign a ref to your dropdown, and with this code you can set focus on it, dropownRef.current.focus()

Answer (score 1):

You can use useRef (only for functional components) hook provided by reactjs.

Steps:

1. Initialize the hook -> const selectRef = useRef(null);
2. Assign it to select component

**select ref={selectRef} onClick={this.handleClick} size={5}**

3. Now in handleClick function add the logic:

   **const handleClick = () => {
   ...your logic;
   if(selectRef.current) selectRef.current.focus(); // add this line
   }**

**For class components**

1. in constructor:

   constructor() {
   this.selectRef = React.createRef();
   }
2. And then in your select component:
   **select ref={this.selectRef} onClick={this.handleClick} size={5}**
3. Then in handleClick function:

```
**const handleClick = () => {
...your logic;
if(this.selectRef.current) this.selectRef.current.focus(); // add this 
line
}**
```

Comment: could you please help me to modify code in class component?

Comment: yeah sure!, let me edit answer

Comment: edited the answer, you can check it

Comment: was it able to solve your issue?

Comment: no it is not working